# How to search with tlmgr?

Tags: tlmgr

I have installed TeX Live 2019 on Unix (macOS 10.14). Now there are some packages, which I forgot to install. For example, I'd like to have `otfinfo` (the binary). How can I find out, which package I need to install with `tlmgr`?

```sh
tlmgr search otfinfo
```

gives no result.

Comment: I think you need the global switch `tlmgr search --global otfinfo` (I can't test as I have everything installed).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks, that works. tlmgr is so opaque to me. You can turn this into an answer, if you want :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the global switch:

```
 tlmgr search --global otfinfo
```

Without the option, tlmgr searches "the names, short descriptions, and long descriptions of all *locally installed*  packages". With the `--global` switch it searches the database.

You can also add the `--all` switch to get more hits (filenames). See https://tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#search for all options.

Comment: Thank you very much Ulrike.